# Use plot_model to produce confidence intervals plot for multiple models

Tags: r, sjplot

I am using the function `plot_model` from the `sjPlot` package to generate a confidence interval plot for a fixed effect linear model (felm). For the individual base model, I encountered no issues, and generated the confidence interval plot effectively. Now, however, I am attempting to do this for multiple similarly-constructed models, but cannot make it work.

An individual model's code is as simple as the following:

`plot <- plot_model(model1,  show.values = TRUE)`

Using the `lapply` function I generated the multiple models, which are now stored as a list object. However, I cannot find the way to put this list object (or its multiple individual models) into the `plot_model` (or `plot_models`) function. I have received various errors, including this one:

`Warning: Could not access model information.Error in if (fam.info$is_linear) transform <- NULL else transform <- "exp" : argument is of length zero`

Is there a way to place multiple similar models from a list into the `plot_model` function, so that the resulting confidence interval plots can be readily compared?

Update: with sample code and error:

`plots <- plot_models(modellist[[1]], modellist[[2]],  show.values = TRUE)`

`` Warning: Could not access model information.Error: Sorry, `model_parameters()` failed with the following error (possible class 'numeric' not supported): $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors ``

Comment: Updated with sample code and error.

Comment: I tried making an felm model and then ploting two copies with plot_models. No problems. I did it with both a list of models and two models entered as separate parameters. Need a data example and code that does this.